# ViewModel concept still exists in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

After answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827377/viewmodel-concept-still-exists-in-asp-net-mvc-core) about whether the ViewModel is still applicable in MVC Core, I now find myself with a similar question in Blazor.

I'm starting to build my first complex Blazor page with a lot of state to manage.  Elements of the page will show/hide and update depending on data entered on other parts of the page.

I've worked with React and Redux in the past and found great value in having a single location for all the state, especially for unit testing purposes.

Accordingly, my plan is to have a view-model that contains not only the data I'm going to persist to the database, but also potentially flags such as `ShowSalesOrdersPanel` that will then be used in `if` statements in the razor view.

My question is, should this view-model be a separate class, or is the `@functions` section of the Blazor razor file effectively the view-model?  Should I just use that instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @functions Block in Blazor fulfills the same functionality as that of Razor Pages. You can define your objects in the @functions Block, instantiate and use them, etc. The @functions Block is actually what we call "code behind." I guess you know all of that, right ?

Right now no formal best practices are available, as Blazor is still under preliminary development. Best practices require a lengthy experience by the community. You can follow samples produced by Asp.Net team to get some ideas of how to develop in Blazor. As for instance, creating a StateApp class whose responsibility to manage the state of components, etc. Currently one should use his experience and knowledge to style his app. As for instance, Create a folder to contain your Model objects, etc., as for instance, define a Customer model class, and then use it in the @functions Block, and elsewhere. To cut it short: No best practices in Blazor yet.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 10):

After asking this question I came across the Microsoft Blazor team's excellent [Blazing Pizzas blazor-workshop worked example](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop).

That example uses a State based approach in a similar way to the approach often adopted in React when using Redux or other Flux based approaches.

This seems like a really good approach that I've found works really well in React.  I've written more about what the State based approach consists of [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56223698/1879019).