# Blazor.net UI not Rendering anything

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

I am developing an Blaor.Net Application , taking reference from many post available on internet . The Problem i am facing that i want to move code from UI to a seprate file to keep razor file clean readable and understandable . For this i am keeping my UI side C# code into a separate component which is inherited from BaseComponent

```
@page "/Item"
@using WebApplication1.Shared
@using WebApplication1.Client.Services;
@inherits ItemComponent

@if (ItemList != null)
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Metal</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in ItemList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.ID</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Category</td>
                    <td>@item.Metal</td>
                    <td>@item.Price</td>
                    <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@functions{
    public List<ItemModel> ItemList;
    ItemComponent IC = new ItemComponent();

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        ItemList = IC.GetItems().Result;
    }
}
```

**ItemComponent.cs**

```
public class ItemComponent : ComponentBase
{
    private string BaseUrl = "http://localhost:52114/";
    public async Task<List<ItemModel>> GetItems()
    {
        HttpClient Http = new HttpClient();
        return await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<ItemModel>>(BaseUrl + "api/Item/GetItems");
    }
}
```

Instead of making api call in UI i want to have it in separate file , Component basically working as a code behind file for razor page here

> Http.GetJsonAsync>(BaseUrl + "api/Item/GetItems");

But After creating component and inheriting it into razor it throw exception

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it. at
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host,
>   Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result() at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result() at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task1 sendTask,
>   HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean
>   disposeCts)    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task1
>   getTask) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.BlazorMonoDebugProxyAppBuilderExtensions.GetOpenedBrowserTabs(String
>   debuggerHost) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.BlazorMonoDebugProxyAppBuilderExtensions.DebugHome(HttpContext
>   context)

Browser got hang after this exception , it can not be closed , only through task manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've still got a little refactoring to do. As I said in my answer to your earlier question, you need to move everything from the `functions` block into the code behind. When using a base class you **should not** mix it with a `functions` block in the view.

In terms of your http call, you don't need to add the base URL this is already done for you, but you should not be newing up a HTTP client either. You should inject an instance into your code behind.

There are a few other slight issues in your code, so I thought it might be easier to rework it to show how it should look.

```
@page "/Item"
@inherits ItemComponent

@if (ItemList != null)
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Metal</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in ItemList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.ID</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Category</td>
                    <td>@item.Metal</td>
                    <td>@item.Price</td>
                    <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

```
public class ItemComponent : ComponentBase
{

    [Inject] HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }

    public List<ItemModel> ItemList;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        ItemList = await GetItems();
    }

    public async Task<List<ItemModel>> GetItems()
    {
        return await HttpClient.GetJsonAsync<List<ItemModel>>("api/Item/GetItems");
    }
}
```

This should work as expected as long as your backend is setup correctly (Example: CORS).

Comment: Thank you somuch for clarification , two things , first is i  have to add base address here otherwise it give error "An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set." Second - Item Component is not debuggable , Control does not enter into this file . Debugger skip component file and go straight to controller

Comment: 1. If you're injecting the HttpClient as I described then the base address is set for you.
2. If you're using client-side Blazor then you need to debug in the browser. Debugging in Visual Studio isn't yet supported.

Comment: Ok , Does this approach will work if i use ViewModel instead of component , any example of that ? , Do i got the same error which i was getting earlier after using component